# How to check number of command line arguments + exception handling

Tags: c#, exception, command-line-arguments

How do I go about checking the number of command line arguments entered and then printing an error if its less than 3.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file1 = args[0];
            string file2 = args[1];
            string file3 = args[2];
```

So if args is < 3, I need to print an erorr message and stop the program without running the next lines of code so that it doesnt give an error. Im just confused. Any help would be grealty appreciated

Comment: `args.Length` will tell you how many there are - same as for any other Array.

Comment: if(ars.length<3){//print error}else{//run prog}

Answer (score 4):

args is an array -- you have access to all methods related to arrays.  So a simple implementation of your question could look like this:

```
if(args.Length < 3)
     throw new ArgumentException("Must have three command line arguments");
```

It's almost always a good idea to ensure your variables aren't null before trying to access values on them (so the code could look like `if(args == null || args.Length < 3)`, but per some commentary on this answer, these applications will never give you a null value for args, so it should be fine to omit that in this one specific case.

Comment: Handy fact - [args is guaranteed to never be null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts)

Comment: How do i go about stopping the code so that nothing else runs if the exception happens

Comment: @ben1299rogers the exception will cause the program to stop unless you catch it and deal with it yourself.